# finding if there is a way from the top to a specific element in 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, union-find

I have a 2-dimensional array, I want to check if there is any way from the top row to a specific element in the array.

The way means: that there is continuously connected **`1`**  from top to the element.

[image]

I've implemented a function to solve it: I can check every single row starting from row 1, if these 2 rows are connected then register their connection points and continue else return `false`(no way).

For example, the first 3 rows connected by these 3 points.

[image]

My JS Implementation:

```js
function isWay(arr, row, col) {
  let count =crate_Nd_Array(arr.length);

  if (arr[row][col] == 0) {
      return false;
  }

  if (arr[row][col] == 1) {
     for(let i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<=col; j++){
           if(isOpen(arr,i,j)){  //is open check if the element is 1 or 0
             if(is_2_rows_connected(arr, i , j)){
  //is_2_rows_connected checks if there is a way between each 2 stacked rows.
                  let countt = count[i-1];
                  countt.push([[i,j], [i-1, j]])
             };
           }
        }
     }
  }

   return count;
}

/**is_2_rows_connected checks if there is a way between every 2 stacked rows. */

function is_2_rows_connected(arr, r, c)
{
  if(isOpen(arr,r,c) && isOpen(arr, r-1, c ))
  {   //isopen returns if T if 1 or 0
         return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now, I can get the connection points between every stacked rows, but I'm stuck here.

It can be solved with `union-find` algorithm, but I don't know how to initialize it. any help please ??

Comment: You only want to allow connection from the top row? What happens in a case where you have more than 1 columns with connections of 1 going down? ... refer to your first photo of the array. Do you register both columns?

Comment: what's your expected return from your function? in your code you are returning an array of connected points, but in your question description it seems you are check if there is a way to a specific point from top row, so return a boolean value?

Comment: so basically, if there is a connection between every stacked rows, then you need to check if the number of connections = number of rows from top to the element, this is a true. else false

Answer (score 1):

You can start from the target cell position and do a standard BFS/DFS pass to visit all reachable cells in the grid. If you reach the top row during this return `true` and if at then end no top row element has been reached return `false`.

Another way to do this would be starting from top row. For this, initially add all top row cells with `1` to queue/stack. From there check if the target cell is reachable using standard BFS/DFS.